# Syslog connector - CEF source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, syslog, confluent-platform

Trying to find an example of how to configure the Confluent syslog connector to accept data in CEF format.  I have the syslog connector up and running, but seeing these kinds of errors in the connect.log, never makes it to my topic:

```
[2020-03-24 23:56:09,181] WARN decode() - Could not parse message. request = 'SyslogRequest{receivedDate=2020-03-24T23:56:09.181, remoteAddress=/<some ip>, rawMessage=Wed Mar 25 00:31:30 2020 1/1/e1 CEF:0|Gigamon|metadata|unknown|4|metadata generation|6|GigamonMdataDeltaBytesRcvd=40 GigamonMdataDeltaPKtsRcvd=1 GigamonMdataFlowStartSysUpTime=264840090 GigamonMdataFlowEndSysUpTime=264840090 proto=6 src=<some ip> dst=<some ip> spt=34846 dpt=9997 }' (io.confluent.connect.syslog.message.SyslogMessageParsingHandler)
```

I configure connector through REST like this:

```
curl localhost:8083/connectors -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "connect-syslog-netflow","config": { "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.syslog.SyslogSourceConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "topics":"syslog-netflow","syslog.port": "2055","confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092", "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1", "type": "CEF" } }'
```

type CEF was weak attempt at telling it incoming format.

Running 5.0.1 confluent distro, one node dev cluster.

Comment: Can you share your connector config? and version details?

Comment: Done, see above.  I also have a few things in connect.props which I assume applies to all connectors, value and key converters json, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working with confluent support we determined problem:

```
rawMessage=Wed Mar 25 00:31:30 2020 ...
```

It works by changing that date to:

```
rawMessage=Mar 25 00:31:30 ...
```

Stripping off day of week and year.

Unfortunately I don't control the netflow source, so I guess I'll need to have some kind of custom transform on data before sending on to connector.